# Redirecting to current page after sign in using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise for user sign in/up. I want to redirect the user from on the page where they were before login. But devise is not redirecting properly. On sign in, it signs in user but throws error on /user/sign_in page:

"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

When i go back and reload the page that it shows user is logged in.

My application controller looks like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
  end
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   request.referrer
  end
end
```

I have used bootstrap modal script on product buy page. It works perfectly for login button used in modal script on page. But gives improper redirecting error for login button in header and hence for every page of app.

What would be the reason?

Comment: Can you also post your `stored_location_for` method

Comment: @rocketscientist not defined it. What should it be?

Comment: @user1977201 i am facing same problem.. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

For your method that will store the user's location before being redirected to a sign in page you will want something like this.

```
  before_filter :store_location

  def store_location
    session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   session[:user_return_to] || request.referrer || root_path
  end
```

This will store the location when a user enters your website in a session variable and then redirect the user to that session variable once they have logged in.

Comment: not working, giving same error. fullpath should be replaced by some other path?

Comment: Hmmm, I would output the result of each method in order see what is getting returned and what the session variable is getting set as.  You can use `puts #variable name` to do this and that will output the values to your log.